# Transpose columns to rows and sum up common column

Tags: sql, database, procedures

Basically I have these columns in a temp table, I would like to group them by the dynamic columns (Payment method) to rows and sum up the tax amount based on the payment method. The Tax column will always be there, so you may consider it a static column. The dynamic columns are stored in a variable @PaymentMethod = [Cash], [Card], etc...

```
Cash |  Card   | Tax
3.00             0.50
3.00             0.50
        5.00     0.70
```

Expected result:

```
Pay Method | Tax 
Cash         1.00 
Card         0.70
```

How do I achieve this? I've looked up on UNPIVOT however, all the payment methods share the same Tax column field and that is actually the field I want to sum up.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `case` for aggregation:

```
select (case when cash is null and card is null then 'neither'
             when cash is not null and card is not null then 'both'
             when cash is not null then 'cash'
             when credit is not null then 'credit'
        end) as pay_method,
       sum(tax)
from t
group by (case when cash is null and card is null then 'neither'
               when cash is not null and card is not null then 'both'
               when cash is not null then 'cash'
               when credit is not null then 'credit'
          end);
```

Comment: I couldn't use it that way because the payment methods will be dynamic. You are hard coding the payment methods.

Comment: @user3543512 . . . They really cannot be dynamic if they are columns in a table.

Comment: They are a temp table. Let's say the columns were all stored in a variable @PaymentMethod = [Cash], [Credit], etc